# Combobox not displaying 'Display Member' properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

Okay I am not understanding why WPF cannot display the 'Display Member' of a combobox item yet can do the 'selected value'.  What is weird is I can explicitly create the display member but not get it back.  In my example below I simplified the real world example that would be using ADO.NET to populate the itemsource but the concept is the same.  I am generating a combobox that generates at runtime from a sql statement.  I want to get the value for one thing but the display for something else.  Is there some extra binding or customization I am missing or just the wrong member of .NET?  I merely want to get 'Display of ...' to get selected back.  If it is not possible that seems kind of weird.  All I get back when I select is 'Value' so I know something is being lost in the transfer.

Any ideas?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFComboBoxTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb" Width="100" Height="50"/>
    <TextBlock Height="100"/>
    <Button x:Name="btn" Content="Click" Click="btn_Click" Width="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Data;

namespace WPFComboBoxTest
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindComboBox(cmb);
    }

    public void BindComboBox(ComboBox cbx)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));

        dt.Rows.Add("Display of One", 1);
        dt.Rows.Add("Display of Two", 2);
        dt.Rows.Add("Display of Three", 3);
        dt.Rows.Add("Display of Four", 4);

        cbx.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
        cbx.DisplayMemberPath = dt.Columns["Value"].ToString();
        cbx.SelectedValuePath = dt.Columns["Id"].ToString();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Selected Value works: " + cmb.SelectedValue
            + "\n\nSelect Display does not though?: " + cmb.DisplayMemberPath
            );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: (facepalm) it was pretty simple.  cmb.DisplayMemberPath needs to be cmb.Text.  The 'Text' was the property I needed to display the display member shown to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(facepalm) it was pretty simple. cmb.DisplayMemberPath needs to be cmb.Text. The 'Text' was the property I needed to display the display member shown to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `ToString` on a column does not sound like a good idea to begin with, not sure how `DataTables` are mapped but i would try

```
cbx.DisplayMemberPath = "Value";
cbx.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your `btn_Click` event Data as Following:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Selected Value works: " + cmb.SelectedValue
            + "\n\nSelect Display does not though?: " + cmb.Text
    );
}
```

I think working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
cbx.DisplayMemberPath = "[Value]";
cbx.SelectedValuePath = "[Id]";
```

It works for me!